# How to add an extra column to the Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Im' using TSQL.

```
SELECT  
     s.Login_Name,
     COUNT( DISTINCT (isnull(s.s1CIDNumber,'')+isnull(s.s1AVATARNumber,''))) AS 'Number of Surveys For the Week Ending on 60/09/2015'    
  FROM [dbSuppHousing].[dbo].[tblSurvey]s
  inner join tblUsers u  on 
   s.Login_Name=u.UserName
  where s.Survey_DT >='06/01/2015' AND s.Survey_DT <='2015-06-09 23:59:59'       
  group by s.Login_Name
```

Currently it display data like :

```
LoginName   Number of Surveys
    MrA   8
    Mrb   4
    mrc   4
    mrd   6
```

How can I show user_ id as  another column? User_id is in tblUser 
and  both tblsurvey and tblUser have 1-1 relationship on Login_Name

So result should look like this:

```
 LoginName   Number of Surveys   User_ID
    MrA           8              33
    Mrb           4              55  
    mrc           4              11 
    mrd           6              07
```

I tried to join these 2 tables and add User_id but every time I get stopped by the well known error "User_id should be part of group by"

No I dont want User_id be part of group by , I just want it to add it to the 3rd column.

Comment: If there is not a possibility that more than one `user_ID` can be associated with a given `LoginName`, why not add it to the group by?

Comment: Why don't you want to add it to group by?

Comment: No each login name has only 1 userid

Comment: @ JamesZ I was worried if that somehow changes the results.

Comment: If User_ID is unique as your question states, it is linked to one and only one login name, then add it to the GROUP BY.  It cannot change your results set if there is no grouping to be had in the data itself.  It is also a very easy test to run your query with and without it to see the results are as anticipated.

Comment: Thanks, So I sholud be worried about the case if somehow User_id's are not unique.?

Comment: If it's not unique simply do a `MIN(user_ID)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user_ID is unique, you can add it to GROUP BY without inflating the record set.  You can also insert your initial query into a temp table and update (with more overhead) to get the user_id, like so:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Users', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Users;


CREATE TABLE #Users
            (login_Name  NVARCHAR(256),
             NumSurveys INT,
             User_ID INT)


INSERT INTO #Users(login_Name, NumSurveys)
SELECT  
     s.Login_Name,
     COUNT( DISTINCT (isnull(s.s1CIDNumber,'')+isnull(s.s1AVATARNumber,''))) AS 'Number of Surveys For the Week Ending on 60/09/2015'    
  FROM [dbSuppHousing].[dbo].[tblSurvey]s
  inner join tblUsers u  on 
   s.Login_Name=u.UserName
  where s.Survey_DT >='06/01/2015' AND s.Survey_DT <='2015-06-09 23:59:59'       
  group by s.Login_Name



UPDATE  #Users
SET  User_ID = User_ID
FROM #Users u 
INNER JOIN tblUsers u2
ON u.login_Name = u2.login_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your GroupBY query into a subselect, and give a label of "a".  Then join the whole subselect to the tblUser and give it a label of "b".  Then join "a" and "b" on LoginID.  Then select a.user_id, and rest of from "b"

```
SELECT a.user_id,b.*
FROM 
(SELECT  
 s.Login_Name,
 COUNT( DISTINCT (isnull(s.s1CIDNumber,'')+isnull(s.s1AVATARNumber,''))) AS 'Number of Surveys For the Week Ending on 60/09/2015'    
  FROM [dbSuppHousing].[dbo].[tblSurvey]s
  inner join tblUsers u  on 
   s.Login_Name=u.UserName
  where s.Survey_DT >='06/01/2015' AND s.Survey_DT <='2015-06-09 23:59:59'       
  group by s.Login_Name) a inner join tblUsers b on a.Login_Name = b.Login_Name
```

Comment: My solution will also work if user_id is not unique.

Comment: Your code gives me error incorrect syntax near FROM

Comment: I originally had a typo of "SELECT a.user_id,b.*" Make sure you use b.*